# How to fire-and-forget in WCF when using wsHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, fire-and-forget

I have a `WCF` service hosted in IIS and it is consumed by an ASP.NET application. Service and client are on diferent servers and communicate over internet.

`Message` security over `wsHttpBinding` is used as the security model (using `X.509` certificate).

I tested the service with `Fiddler` and everything seems OK unless for a single call there are 4 sessions in fiddler (two round-trips). I don't need sessions with `WCF` and want my calling threads (which are asp.net worker threads), not to be blocked when calling a `WCF` method.

How can I achieve fire-and-forget pattern when using a `WCF` service (I can change the service contract if needed) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire and forget (One-Way operation) only says that your operation doesn't return any result and so client doesn't have to wait for server processing. But it has nothing to do with infrastracture calls you see in fiddler. First of all turn off `estabilishSecurityContext` and `negotiateServiceCredentials` in your `security` element (these are turned on by default) and try it again.

Comment: So, doesn't it disable my security model (I need message security without transport security) ?

Comment: @Xaqron: If your security mode will be still set to message it will not disable security but by disabling estabilishSecurityContext you will turn off security session and by disabling negotiateServiceCredentials you will turn off automatic transfer of service certificate to client - client will have to receive certificate out of the band. It will reduce roundtrips.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say "fire-and-forget" you are referring to a web service call that yields no return parameters. WCF has the notion of [One-Way Method invocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx) that might help you here.